# Marklogic 8 : Scheduled task do not start and no logs

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

I scheduled a data extraction with an Xquery query on ML 8.0.6 using the "scheduler tasks".

My Xquery query (this query works if I copy/paste it in the ML web console and I get a file available on AWS S3):

```
xdmp:save("s3://XX.csv",let $nl := "&#10;"

return
document {

for $book in collection("books")/books
return (root($book)/bookId||","||
        $optin/updatedDate||$nl
)
})
```

My scheduled task :

- Task enabled : yes
- Task path : /home/bob/extraction.xqy
- task root  : /
- task type: hourly
- task period : 1
- task start time: 8 past the hour
- task database : mydatabase
- task modules : file system
- task user : admin
- task host: XX
- task priority : higher

Unfortunately, my script is not executed because no file is generated on AWS S3 (the storage used)and I do not have any logs.

Any idea to :
1/debug a job in the scheduler task?
2/ See the job running at the expected time ?

Thanks,
Romain.

Answer (score 3):

First, I would try take a look at the *ErrorLog.txt* because it will probably show you where to look for the problem.

```
xdmp:filesystem-file(concat(xdmp:data-directory(),"/","Logs","/","ErrorLog.txt"))
```

- Where is the script located logically: Has it been uploaded to the content database, modules database, or *./MarkLogic/Modules* directory?
- If this is a cluster, have you specified which host it's running on?  If so, and using the filesystem modules, then ensure the script exists in the *./MarkLogic/Modules* directory of the specified host.  Inf not, and using the filesystem modules, then ensure the script exists in the *./MarkLogic/Modules* directory of **all** the hosts of the cluster.

As for seeing the job running, you can check the *http://servername:8002/dashboard/* and take a look at the *[Query Execution](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/monitoring/dashboard)* tab see the running processes, or you can get a snapshot of the process by taking a look at the **Status** page of the task server (**Configure > Groups > [group name] > Task Server: *Status*** and click **show more** button)

Comment: THanks Michael. Not sure to understand what you said about the location of the script. I put the script in the home of a user : /home/toto/test.xqy Is-it OK to do that or do I have to put it in the ML folder ? If yes, how can I specify the path of the file in the task type/task root ? It's not very clear in the documentation

Comment: To execute a script via Task manager, the script either needs to be in one of the databases on the system, or within the Modules folder in the MarkLogic install directory on the host which is calling it.

Comment: Ok thanks Michael. But in this case how to fill the two variables task path and task root?

Comment: Task path is the filesystem path or URI of the script, task root is typically `/`.  You may have to use xdmp:filesystem-directory("/path/to/file") on the filesystem path to ensure the server has permissions.